# Как настроить круговое логгирование в SpringBoot проекте?

Tags: java, логирование, spring-boot, slf4j

Добрый день!

Есть проект на SpringBoot, используется org.slf4j.Logger, лежит на aws. Как реализовать круговое логирование? Нужно чтобы логи писались в несколько файлов по кругу: день_1, день_2, день_3... день_n; и помимо этого делились по уровням:день_1_warn, день_1_error...

Спасибо за любые подсказки, ссылки и прочее.

Comment: Смотрите Rolling в документации к конкретному логгеру, который вы используете (Log4j2 там или Logback).

Comment: спасибо. Вы меня наставили на путь истинный)